# Get name of next month

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone have any examples of how I could cycle one month forwards in VBA?

Currently I have a source sheet that has the month value "October". I have a macro button embedded in the worksheet that creates a new sheet and I need it to take the value from the cell that current has this month value and place it in the new sheet but one month forwards, i.e. "November" in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either make a reusable function that returns what you are looking for or try a combination of Month/MonthName functions to get what you are looking for.

```
Function GetNextMonth(Byval currentMonth as string) As string
   Select Case currentMonth
      Case "January"
          GetNextMonth = "February"
      Case "February"
          GetNextMonth = "March"
      Case "March"
          GetNextMonth = "April"
      Case "April"
          GetNextMonth = "May"
      Case "May"
          GetNextMonth = "June"
      Case "June"
          GetNextMonth = "July"
      Case "July"
          GetNextMonth = "August"
      Case "August"
          GetNextMonth = "September"
      Case "September"
          GetNextMonth = "October"
      Case "October"
          GetNextMonth = "November"
      Case "November"
          GetNextMonth = "December"
      Case "December"
          GetNextMonth = "January"
    End Select
End Function
```

Even shorter combination method:

```
Function GetNextMonth(ByVal currentMonth as string) As String
    GetNextMonth = MonthName(Month(DateValue("01-" & currentMonth & "-2000"))+1)
End Function
```

Give VBA a date using your current month name, have it convert it, then grab the month number from it, add one and return the month name.  However, you may need to add a check to see if the current Month is 12 (edge case).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - I do suppose VBA and VB.NET are not the same are they?

Answer (score 5):

As  User Defined Function

```
Function NextMonth(m As String) As String
    NextMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, DateValue("1 " & m & " 2000")), "mmmm")
End Function
```

or as an Excel Formula (where `D1` contains the Month you want to offset from)

```
=TEXT(EDATE( DATEVALUE("1 " & D1 & " 2000"),1), "mmmm")
```

Comment: For a formula you can use =TEXT((1&D1)+31,"MMMM")

Answer (score 0):

**Even shorter udf without explicit `DateAdd` function**

This function accepts both strings as well as numbers, so the `currMonth` argument could be "January", "Jan" or 1.

```
Function NextMonth$(currMonth)
    NextMonth = Format(CDate(currMonth & "/2 0") + 30, "mmmm")
End Function
```

**Note**

So the `CDate` function would transform the above input in a date of *Jan 2nd 1900* (=year 0), the next month is reached for sure by adding 30 days (average month). The `Format` function via argument `mmmm` returns the next month's full name, e.g. `"February"`.